# Creating a sort method using recursive method in Ruby (without using .sort)

Tags: ruby, sorting, recursion

I have tried to recreate the ".sort" function in Ruby, using the recursive method. However, all I get as the output is 'Nil' and I'm not sure why. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
def sort arr
  if arr.length > 0
    result << arr.min
    arr.delete(arr.min)
    sort arr
  else
    new_array.length == 0
    result
  end
end
```

Comment: Both `result` and `new_array` appear in your code out of nowhere.

Comment: Somehow I think you've invented a sorting method even worse than a bubble sort. If you want to learn about programming, why not implement a simple [tree sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sort)? There's a lot of [different methods you can use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

Comment: Also worth noting that `delete` [removes **all** matches](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-delete) to the value, so bye-bye duplicates...

Comment: Thanks! working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with what you have is that you have a couple of unassigned variables `result` and `new_array`.

Here's an example of a custom sort method that uses `partition` with a recursive method. It takes the first element of your array and splits your array into two parts using `partition` into  a group containing elements lesser and greater than this first element using recursion.

```
def sort(arr)
  return [] if arr.length == 0

  f_element = arr.shift
  less, greater = arr.partition {|x| x < f_element }
  sort(less) + [f_element] + sort(greater)
end

arr = "happiness".chars
print sort(arr)
#=> ["a", "e", "h", "i", "n", "p", "p", "s", "s"]
```

Comment: No problem! Good luck :-)